# Will my AdSense Account be affected, if I swap the Blogger platform for the WordPress platform, on my website?

Tags: wordpress, blogger, adsense

I currently run a [Blogger](https://www.blogger.com/) website, with it's own [programming shortcut](http://www.programmingshortcut.com/).  I no longer wish to use the Blogger platform on my website.  Instead, I wish to implement the WordPress platform into my website; naturally, keeping the same domain name.

How can I replace the Blogger platform with WordPress and then host Google AdSense on my newly created WordPress website?  Upon a successful exchange of platforms, will this affect my Google AdSense site Advertisements/Account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Migrating from Blogger to WordPress:**

By the looks of it, you already own the domain name.  So that is one task completed.  You now need to do the following:

1. Find a Hosting company and purchase the required hosting.  Shared Server, VPS, Dedicated Server etc.  Ideally, you will want to purchase the Hosting with the same company you purchased the Domain name from, to save you some headache on Nameservers etc.
2. Once you have purchased your hosting, you will need to point your domain to the hosting server.  This will involve modifying your DNS Settings.  Something, your hosting provider should be able to assist you with,
3. Once you have got your hosting setup and your domain pointing to your hosting, speak to your Hosting company to see if they offer a 'One-Click' service which installs WordPress onto your domain for you.  If they do not, your next step will require you to [download](https://wordpress.org/download/) and then [install](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress) WordPress.
4. Once you have WordPress setup, head over to www.your-domain.com/wp-admin.  This will take you to the final setup phases of WordPress, where you will be able to access the WordPress Dashboard.
5. Once you are in the Dashboard, you will need to install a Theme (You will see many free WordPress Themes within Dashboard > Themes > Add New).  Alternatively, you can purchase/create your own theme.
6. Since you are currently using Blogger, I can see your URL structure is:  `domain > Yeah > Month > Post Name`.  As a result, you are going to need to head into 'Dashboard > Settings > Permalinks'.  Then select 'Custom' and enter `/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%.html/` and then select save.  This ensures that WordPress copies the same URL structure of your existing Blog Content on Blogger.
7. As far as I am aware, you cannot import your pages from Blogger to WordPress.  As a result, it will be a case of manually transferring the data over within the 'Add Page' feature, within the WordPress Dashboard.  It is fairly user friendly.
8. As for the Blog Posts you have created, you can import these from Blogger to WordPpress with the [Blogger Importer Extended](https://wordpress.org/plugins/blogger-importer-extended/) Plugin.  To install this, head to Dashboard > Plugins and then search for 'Blogger Importer Extended'.
9. Simply follow the on screen instructions and hopefully, this will be all that is needed.
10. Once you have imported your Pages, Posts, Comments etc, go through the website, to see how it looks.  There may be a few changes to the overall style and formats, due to how WordPress and Blogger differs.  Anything you don't like, just select 'Edit Page' and modify accordingly.
11. It may also be worth installing the [Broken Link Checker](https://wordpress.org/plugins/broken-link-checker/) Plugin.  Use the same approach to installing, as the above Plugin.  What this does, is highlights if any links are not working.  You can then go ahead and modify accordingly.

**Uploading Google AdSense to WordPress site:**

The first port of call is to ensure that you are compliant with [Google AdSense's Policies](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/48182?hl=en-GB), as to ensure you are not violating any terms and conditions.  Otherwise, you could find that you Account could become suspended.

Rather than me provide a step by step guide on how to upload Google AdSense Adverts to your website, simply follow this [article >>>](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-add-google-adsense-to-your-wordpress-site/)  It may look a little awkward but t is fairly straight forward.

That should be about it for now.  There will no doubt be many tweaks along the way but this should get you going for now.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Not a problem. Best of luck with your website. :-)